# Generating combinations between a range of numbers. How?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had the following code that was working just fine and then I've updated to a new version of Python. What I don't understand is why it will only work up to 10 combinations. If you set variables **combination_cap** and **range_to** to higher than 10 the program just hangs. No error. Nothing.

Here's my code:

```
import itertools
import subprocess
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
        return
else:
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("clear", shell=True)
        return

def generateCombinationRange():

    combination_cap = 10
    range_from = 1
    range_to   = 10

    combination_list = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap)+1), 6))
    combination_list_lenght = len(combination_list)

    output_file = open('F' + str(range_from) + 'T' + str(range_to) + 'OF' + str(combination_list_lenght) + '_comibnations.csv', 'w')

    index = 0

    for each_combination in combination_list:

        index += 1

        #print(''.join(str(each_combination)) + '\n')

        if index >= range_from:

            output_file.write(str(index) + ', '
                            + str(each_combination[0]) + ', '
                            + str(each_combination[1]) + ', '
                            + str(each_combination[2]) + ', '
                            + str(each_combination[3]) + ', '
                            + str(each_combination[4]) + ', '
                            + str(each_combination[5]) + '\n'
                            )
        if index >= range_to:
            output_file.close()
            break

    output_file.close()

generateCombinationRange()
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. It works fine for me. I suspect may not have enough RAM in your computer.

Comment: So you were able to set combination_cap and range_to to say 1000 and it created a CSV file for you with a 1000 combinations indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the line `list(itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap)+1), 6))`. If the numbers are high, you're generating an enormous list that's going to chew through all of your RAM. What you should do is use it as a generator, so it only generates the numbers you actually use. This version will work with any set of values for `combination_cap` and `range_to` because it only stores one combination in memory at a time.

```
def generate_combination_range():
    combination_cap = 100
    range_from = 1
    range_to = 100

    output_file = open(
        'F' + str(range_from) + 'T' + str(range_to) + 'OF' + '_comibnations.csv', 'w')

    index = 0

    for each_combination in itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap) + 1), 6):

        index += 1

        # print(''.join(str(each_combination)) + '\n')

        if index >= range_from:

            output_file.write(str(index) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[0]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[1]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[2]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[3]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[4]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[5]) + '\n'
                              )
        if index >= range_to:
            output_file.close()
            break

    output_file.close()
```

Also, style note, it's generally prefered to use `enumerate` instead of manually managing an index. `for index, each_combination in enumerate(itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap) + 1), 6)):`

Comment: Thanks a lot Morgan. I just had a quick question. Is there a way to make the generator do exactly what it does but, only output to file, combinations that possess a Prime Number Index?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Ok. Notice how my code generates an Index for each combination. This index number ranges from 1 to say... 10. How many prime numbers exist between 1 and 10? We have 2, 3, 5, 7. Is there a way to make the generator output only these indexes and their respective combinations to a csv file? Hopefully this clarifies.

Comment: Sure, it would absolutely be possible to do that. That's a different question though. Why don't you try and then ask another question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a Memory error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\zila\zilawww\t.py", line 54, in <module>
     generateCombinationRange()
   File "C:\zila\zilawww\t.py", line 25, in generateCombinationRange
    combination_list = list(itertools.combinations((range(1, int(combination_cap)+1)), 6))
    MemoryError
```

Remove the "list"

```
combination_list = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap)+1), 6))
```

To make it a generator and save the memory (you won't be able to use it on len though)

```
combination_gen = (itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap)+1), 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the time to incorporate your answer into my code and now I have the finished product. I would like to share the complete code with everyone who may be interested.

```
import subprocess
import os
import itertools
import math

if os.name == 'nt':
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
        return
else:
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("clear", shell=True)
        return


#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def main_menu():

    while True:

        main_menu_selected_option = 0

        # MAIN MENU - PARENT
        while main_menu_selected_option not in range(1, 4):

            try:
                clear_console()
                print ('')
                print ('  Combination Generator v1.0 - Menu')
                main_menu_selected_option = int(input('''
      1. All indexed combinations for combination cap.
      2. All Prime indexed combinations for combination cap.
      3. Extract range of indexed combinations for combination cap.
      4. Extract Prime range of indexed combinations for combination cap.

      Enter Option: '''))

            except ValueError:
                #print ('Not an integer!')
                #clear_console()
                #print ('')
                #print ('  Lotery Systems - Menu')
                continue
            else:
                if main_menu_selected_option == 1:
                    menu_1()
                else:
                    if main_menu_selected_option == 2:
                        menu_2()
                    else:
                        if main_menu_selected_option == 3:
                            menu_3()
                        else:
                            if main_menu_selected_option == 4:
                                menu_4()
                            else:
                                clear_console()
                                main_menu()



#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def menu_1():

    combination_cap = 0

    # 1ST MENU = CHILD.
    while int(combination_cap) not in range(1, 42+1):

        combination_cap = int(input('''
        Enter combination Cap: '''))

        print ('')
        print ('  Generating combinations for combination cap.')
        print ('  Please wait...')
        menu_1_execute(combination_cap)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def menu_2():

    combination_cap = 0

    # 2ND MENU = CHILD.
    while int(combination_cap) not in range(1, 42+1):

        combination_cap = int(input('''
        Enter combination Cap: '''))

        print ('')
        print ('  Generating combinations for combination cap.')
        print ('  Please wait...')
        menu_2_execute(combination_cap)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def menu_3():

    combination_cap = 0
    range_from = 0
    range_to   = 0

    # 3RD MENU = CHILD.
    while int(combination_cap) not in range(1, 42+1):

        try:

            combination_cap = int(input('''
            Enter combination Cap: '''))

            range_from = int(input('''
            Enter from: '''))

            range_to = int(input('''
            Enter to: '''))

        except ValueError:
            #print ('Not an integer!')
            #clear_console()
            #print ('')
            #print ('  Lotery Systems - Menu')
            continue
        else:
            if range_from < range_to:
                print ('')
                print ('  Generating range of combinations for combination cap.')
                print ('  Please wait...')
                menu_3_execute(combination_cap, range_from, range_to)
            else:
                continue


#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def menu_4():

    combination_cap = 0
    range_from = 0
    range_to   = 0

    # 3RD MENU = CHILD.
    while int(combination_cap) not in range(1, 42+1):

        try:

            combination_cap = int(input('''
            Enter combination Cap: '''))

            range_from = int(input('''
            Enter from: '''))

            range_to = int(input('''
            Enter to: '''))

        except ValueError:
            #print ('Not an integer!')
            #clear_console()
            #print ('')
            #print ('  Lotery Systems - Menu')
            continue
        else:
            if range_from < range_to:
                print ('')
                print ('  Generating Prime range of combinations for combination cap.')
                print ('  Please wait...')
                menu_4_execute(combination_cap, range_from, range_to)
            else:
                continue


#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def menu_1_execute(combination_cap):

    index = 0

    output_file = open('all_indexed_combinations.csv', 'w')

    combination_generator = (itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap) + 1), 6))

    for each_combination in combination_generator:

        index += 1

        output_file.write(str(index) + ', '
                          + str(each_combination[0]) + ', '
                          + str(each_combination[1]) + ', '
                          + str(each_combination[2]) + ', '
                          + str(each_combination[3]) + ', '
                          + str(each_combination[4]) + ', '
                          + str(each_combination[5]) + '\n'
                          )

    #Stamp Combination Cap
    output_file.write('Cap: ' + ', ' + str(combination_cap) + '\n')
    #Stamp Combinations Total
    output_file.write('Total: ' + ', ' + str(index) + '\n')

    output_file.close()

    os.rename('all_indexed_combinations.csv',str(index) + '_combinations.csv')


#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def menu_2_execute(combination_cap):

    index = 0
    prime_index = 0

    output_file = open('all_prime_indexed_combinations.csv', 'w')

    combination_generator = (itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap) + 1), 6))

    for each_combination in combination_generator:

        index += 1

        if isPrime(index):

            prime_index += 1

            output_file.write(str(index) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[0]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[1]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[2]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[3]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[4]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[5]) + '\n'
                              )


    #Stamp Combination Cap
    output_file.write('Cap: ' + ', ' + str(combination_cap) + '\n')
    #Stamp Prime Combinations Total
    output_file.write('Total: ' + ', ' + str(prime_index) + '\n')

    output_file.close()

    os.rename('all_prime_indexed_combinations.csv',str(prime_index) + '_prime_combinations.csv')


#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def menu_3_execute(combination_cap, range_from, range_to):

    index = 0

    output_file = open('Range_F' + str(range_from) + 'T' + str(range_to) + '_combinations.csv', 'w')

    combination_generator = (itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap) + 1), 6))

    for each_combination in combination_generator:

        index += 1

        if index >= range_from:

            output_file.write(str(index) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[0]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[1]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[2]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[3]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[4]) + ', '
                              + str(each_combination[5]) + '\n'
                              )

        if index >= range_to:
            output_file.close()
            break

    output_file.close()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------


def menu_4_execute(combination_cap, range_from, range_to):

    index = 0

    output_file = open('Prime_Range_F' + str(range_from) + 'T' + str(range_to) + '_combinations.csv', 'w')

    combination_generator = (itertools.combinations(range(1, int(combination_cap) + 1), 6))

    for each_combination in combination_generator:

        index += 1

        if index >= range_from:

            if isPrime(index):

                output_file.write(str(index) + ', '
                                  + str(each_combination[0]) + ', '
                                  + str(each_combination[1]) + ', '
                                  + str(each_combination[2]) + ', '
                                  + str(each_combination[3]) + ', '
                                  + str(each_combination[4]) + ', '
                                  + str(each_combination[5]) + '\n'
                                  )

        if index >= range_to:
            output_file.close()
            break

    output_file.close()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def isPrime(n):

    if n < 2:
        return False

    i = 2

    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):

        if (n % i == 0):
            return False

    return True

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

#Initialize Application
main_menu()
```